# Connect smartphone to Samsung TV Emulator

Tags: emulation, samsung-smart-tv

I installed emulator (Tizen SDK) and successfuly started it. But want to connect my Samsung Smartphone to this emulator with Smart View or with another App. If it is possible, how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

If you connect your Samsung Device (like Z1, Z3) to Tizen SDK, you can install and launch your application which you write in SDK into the connected Device. You you wirte Smart View or other apps. you can install and launch it also. In order to connect Samsung Device with SDK, the certificate issued from Samsung is needed.